# Rollercoaster Project

Tags: python, if-statement, break

I am supposed to filter the ages of the users through the following rule: if users >=120 cm then `print("You can ride the rollercoaster!")`, if users <=119 cm then `print ("Sorry, you must grow taller, see you next time.")`

Everything is going ok with the code when users are <=119, output:

```
> Welcome to the rollercoaster! Enter your height in cm, please: 52
> Sorry, you must grow taller, see you next time.
```

But when users are >=120, this happens:

```
> Welcome to the rollercoaster! Enter your height in cm, please: 178 You
> can ride the rollercoaster! Enter your age, please: 80 You are more
> than 70 years old, you won a free ride, enjoy.! 
> Sorry, you must grow taller, see you next time.
```

As you can see, the last output line it should not be happening.
Is there some way to `break` the if statement? I've tried the `break` function and I got a:

```
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

This is the whole code:

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height = int(input("Enter your height in cm, please: "))
if height >= 120:
  print("You can ride the rollercoaster!")
  age = int(input("Enter your age, please: "))
  if age < 12:
    print ("Please pay $5. Enjoy!")
  elif age <= 18:
    print("Please pay $7. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 18 and age <= 44:
    print("Please pay $12. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 45 and age <=55:
    print ("Everything is going to be ok. Have a free ride on us!")
  elif age <= 69:
   print ("Please pay $9. Enjoy!")
  else:
    print (f"You are more than 70 years old, you won a free ride, enjoy.!")
if height >= 300:
  print ("For security reasons, you are reasigned to the next rollercoaster.")
  age = int(input("Enter your age, please: "))
  if age < 12:
    print ("Please pay $5. Enjoy!")
  elif age <= 18:
    print("Please pay $7. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 18 and age <= 44:
    print("Please pay $12. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 45 and age <=55:
    print ("Everything is going to be ok. Have a free ride on us!")
  elif age <= 69:
   print ("Please pay $9. Enjoy!")
  else:
    print (f"You are more than 70 years old, you won a free ride, enjoy.!")
else:
  print ("Sorry, you must grow taller, see you next time.")
```

Comment: Did you mean `elif height >= 300`? As of now, your first `if` block is independent of the next `if...else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed an *elif* statement in the main condition.

Try this:

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height = int(input("Enter your height in cm, please: "))
if height >= 120 and height <300:
  print("You can ride the rollercoaster!")
  age = int(input("Enter your age, please: "))
  if age < 12:
    print ("Please pay $5. Enjoy!")
  elif age <= 18:
    print("Please pay $7. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 18 and age <= 44:
    print("Please pay $12. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 45 and age <=55:
    print ("Everything is going to be ok. Have a free ride on us!")
  elif age <= 69:
   print ("Please pay $9. Enjoy!")
  else:
    print (f"You are more than 70 years old, you won a free ride, enjoy.!")
elif height >= 300:
  print ("For security reasons, you are reasigned to the next rollercoaster.")
  age = int(input("Enter your age, please: "))
  if age < 12:
    print ("Please pay $5. Enjoy!")
  elif age <= 18:
    print("Please pay $7. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 18 and age <= 44:
    print("Please pay $12. Enjoy!")
  elif age >= 45 and age <=55:
    print ("Everything is going to be ok. Have a free ride on us!")
  elif age <= 69:
   print ("Please pay $9. Enjoy!")
  else:
    print (f"You are more than 70 years old, you won a free ride, enjoy.!")
else:
  print ("Sorry, you must grow taller, see you next time.")
```

See the difference?

Comment: Shouldn't the order of those first two blocks be reversed?  You'll never hit the `elif height >= 300` otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I see it, I'll try it and tell you then. Thanks.!
Is made in a hypothetical situation and was ordered so. I must fix it.

Comment: Yeah I added another condition for that @Samwise

Comment: Was excellent I substitute the if height >= 300: for an elif height >= 300: 

Is fixed.!!

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Also, check the other condition that I added *if height >= 120 and height <300:* otherwise you will not hit the height =>300 statement (since 300 is also greater than 120, it will hit the first height =>120 statement)

Comment: Thanks for that aclaration Mr. Goku, I searched for the block code and make some updates taking into account the code you added before "if height >= 120 and height <300:", 'cause "if height >= 300:" then I needed to print ("For security reasons, you are reasigned to the next rollercoaster.") 

Consecuentally I had to erase the last part of the code, because was repeating.

Thank you.!